# do I need to restart server after hitting breakpoint every time? (IntelliJ, Java 11)

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, server, breakpoints

I am currently working on a large code that will take a long time to run again. When I put breakpoint in the code and the code stops, do I need to restart the server every time? I have to troubleshoot a lot of code, and do not have time to restart the server every time.

Comment: You mean after you modified your code?

Comment: This is the first time I post on this site, so I see now that I did not include all the details needed.. Sorry for that

Comment: What happens if you immediately "continue" from the breakpoint?

Comment: the server just stops, and I can no longer do things in the application. I then have to start everything again and set a new breakpoint, but I want to check everything at the same time and jump from breakpoint to breakpoint without having to run everything again and spend a lot of time logging in and getting to the point I was at

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA you can try `Run | Debugging Actions | Resume Program`.

Answer (score 1):

No, a breakpoint stops the execution in the caught StackFrame at the position the breakpoint was set and triggered. After that, you can either continue stepping through manually line-by-line deciding if you either go into the execution of the given line or step over it (you can also step back - out of the method you are currently at). Or you could skip to the next breakpoint.

But if you make any changes, the code has to recompile and the server has to restart for your changes to take effect.

A more enterprise approach would be to write unit tests for the bits and pieces you tinker with and test them in isolation.
Depending on the number of dependencies it could mean runtime of milliseconds up to a couple of seconds. Take a look at [Test-Driven-Development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development).

It is never too late to start writing tests. ;)

Comment: As I understood, he thinks about the necessity of restarting the server himself, not an external forceful restart.

Comment: By external, I was referring to the coughed context, hence the doings of other threads to be external. But yes, the possibility is there.

Comment: I'm probably a little bad at explaining, but when I put a breakpoint in the code, and the application hits that point, the whole application stops working and I have to run the whole program (from intelliJ and start the program again). This happens every time.

Comment: Maybe you are hitting the wrong "play button".  The play button you should press is on the lower left of the application, not the run button you press when running the application. Compare with [this demo from JetBrains](https://youtu.be/59RC8gVPlvk?t=629)

Comment: The demo solved my problem, thanks a lot for the help!!  It is quite obvious that I have to work a little more with troubleshooting and testing in the future, but thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @FreddyFrog, I think I had similar issues switching from Eclipse. Happy to help.